# What is the best way to get two lists of different object types from the same observable in javarx on Android?

Tags: java, android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java

I have a retrofit api call that returns a javarx observable. Here is the retrofit interface

```
@GET("/myobjects")
Observable<List<MyObject>> getMyObjectsObservable();
```

Then I have a repository method:

```
public Observable<List<MyObject>> getMyObjectsObservable(){
    return api.getMyObjectsObservable();
}
```

In my viewmodel, I have a method that subscribes to the javarx observable returned by the repository. Inside the method, the observable chain in which I subscribe in that method sets values for two MutableLiveData objects that are observed by my activity. One MutableLiveData, "succeededLiveData", holds a boolean which determines if the API call succeeded and displays this for the user in the activity, and the other "myObjectStringsListLiveData" is a list of strings with information from a MyObject object that will be displayed in a listview in the activity. Here is that observable chain:

```
Disposable disposable = myObjectsRepository.getMyObjectsObservable()
    .concatMapIterable(myObject -> myObject)
    .map(myObject -> myObject.getString1() + " And " + myObject.getString2())
    .toList()
    .doOnError(throwable -> {succeededLiveData.postValue(false);
                            myObjectStringsListLiveData.postValue(null);})
    .retry(4)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(myObjectStringsList -> {
                succeededLiveData.setValue(true);
                myObjectStringsListLiveData.setValue(myObjectStringsList);
            },
            throwable -> {
                succeededLiveData.setValue(false);
                myObjectStringsListLiveData.setValue(null);});
```

Now I realized that I actually need the original list of my MyObjects from the observable to be stored in `List<MyObject> myObjectsList` which is a field of my viewmodel, not just the `List<String>` that is stored in my LiveData "myObjectStringsListLiveData". This means that I need a way to extract the myObjectsList from the observable before all the mapping. I can't observe the myObjectsObservable twice, once before the mapping, and then one mapped like my code above, because that would cause two API calls which I obviously do not want. At least it is my understanding that that would happen, as observables execute the code separately for each subscriber.

So I can only personally think of two possible solutions as I am still a javarx noob. One would be to use a type of Subject that subscribes to the retrofit myObjectsObservable so that the API wouldn't be called twice and then subsequently subscribe to that subject twice in my viewmodel. Although I am not quite sure how to implement this, but I think I could figure it out.

The other option I can think of would be to subscribe only once, and inside the lambda I pass the subscribe() method, store the `List<MyObject` emitted by the Observable, and then instead of using the JavaRx map/concatMapIterable/toList() operators, use the java Stream library inside the lambda as well, and use that to map the myObjectsList to `List<String>` that will be posted to the myObjectStringsListLiveData. A downside to this would that this would occur on the main thread I believe. Although maybe I could change the "setValue" methods to "postValue" methods and observeOn a background thread. I am not really sure if that is okay to use the viewmodel in the background like that.

The second solution doesn't seem too elegant. Is it wise to do stuff with a viewmodel in the background? Maybe the first way with a Subject is better?

What do you all think is the best way?

Also, as a bonus question, that is somewhat unrelated to the first question, I was wondering if postValue in MutableLiveData will always execute in order, like how I do so in my lambdas in the observable chain, because I will get a NullPointerException in my activity if `succeededLiveData.getValue()` is called after OnChanged is called for the MyObjectStringsList that I observe in my activity. Will postValue always propagate to each respective LiveData observer in the order they are called?

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: "Now I realized that I actually need the original list of my MyObjects from the observable to be stored in List<MyObject> myObjectsList" - use a `ConnectableObservable` that shares one subscription to the upstream but can publish to multiple subscribers - http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/observables/ConnectableObservable.html

Comment: Thanks I did this and it works. For anyone wondering how I implemented it, I returned the observable from the repository to the viewmodel, moved my retry() and doOnError() operators to that observable and then called .publish() on that same observable chain and stored it in a ConnectableObservable<List<MyObject>> called connectable. Then I did two separate observable chains from that connectable and subscribed for each of my aforementioned needs and after that I called connect on the connectable. Worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't a simple `doOnNext` after `myObjectsRepository.getMyObjectsObservable()` work in this case?

Comment: I am not the right person to answer on which is better as I am just learning JavaRx and Android, but I did get that to work with doOnNext() in a little test I just did on some very similar code (not the original) including with correct threading as well. I was wondering if either is a better approach. Your way seems simpler @Fred however the threading is slightly more complicated, but still simpler overall.

Comment: I don't see why the threading is any different. To the best of my knowledge it works like any other rx method/operator. Could you elaborate? The reason why I think `doOnNext` or any of the `doOn*` methods for that matter is more appropriate is because you describe kind of a side effect/saving state, which I think the `doOn*` methods are the most appropriate for.

Comment: @Fred I meant in order to save List<MyObject> on the main thread, which would be the case implementing the connectable observer, I had to do an observeOn the main thread before doOnNext, and then I had to do another observeOn in order to switch the rest of the downstream like the mapping, toList, concatmap, doOnError operators and then one more observeOn right before subscribe in order to switch back to the main thread.

Comment: @Fred Now I am a noob in android/Rx/developing, so I am not exactly sure if its necessary but I felt weird saving the state in the background thread of my repository when my Main thread would need access to the list, maybe I could just synchronize repository List<MyObject> get and set method to avoid any problems and avoid doing the aforementioned extra threading I am talking about, Idk if that is a good idea either though cuz it could hold up the main thread possibly.

Comment: ah! I get it now. I think moving it to the mainthread is better for the reasons you already mentioned. Ideally, you should try to find a way where you wouldn't need to keep this in memory or maybe even just save it in `subscribe`. That might not be straight forward though.